# when i export my file to .FBX it is showing some glitches in output , the issue affects in places i used a option in edit mode face intersect(boolean)

Tags: export, error, .fbx

When i exported my work in .FBX format is it showing some glitches and in many place when it seems like it is trying to merge or something in the area where i used the option in edit mode face menu intersect boolean , the image supporting will be provided below so by looking that you will be completely able to understand the issue [image: export details]The export settings i used [image: back view of fbx file] The back view of exported file looks everything messy [image: main view]main front view of file looks everything messy [image: other info]some other options in 3d view app showing some additional info[image: object mode image from blender]blender object mode image loos fine and perfect [image: edit mode]edit mode image blender for supporting the helper for giving the solution[image: the option i used to put holes]this is the option i used to put holes in many places and those areas are showing glitches

Comment: hello could you please share the object? pasteall.org/blend

Comment: @Gunt.r you mean you need the project file i am working on , that's totally impossible bro sry